# Update-Database command in SqlMigrations always throws an exception

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying out the [SqlMigrations package](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/EntityFramework.SqlMigrations) for EntityFramework 4.1 and am following the steps in [this tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/07/27/code-first-migrations-walkthrough-of-august-2011-ctp.aspx).

Unfortunately I cannot get `Update-Database` to work. Calling it always produces the same exception:

```
PM> Update-Database
No pending custom scripts found.
Ensuring database matches current model.
Update-Database : The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Common.Diagnostics.EtwProvider' threw an exception.
At line:1 char:16
+ Update-Database <<<< 
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Update-Database], TypeInitializationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.TypeInitializationException,System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Commands.MigrateCommand
```

I am on Windows XP. Is it possible that XP is not supported?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SqlMigrations are dependent on [Entity Framework 4.1 Update 1](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=26825) which states in requirements:

> Supported Operating Systems: Windows 7, Windows Server 2003, Windows
>   Server 2008, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Vista

So it is possible that it doesn't work with Windows XP. Especially when error come from ETW it is more then expected that problem is unsupported OS.

Comment: Hmm, might be time to ask my boss for an upgrade :)